# Remove all files of a certain type except for one type in linux terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

On my computer running Ubuntu, I have a folder full of hundreds files all named "index.html.n" where n starts at one and continues upwards. Some of those files are actual html files, some are image files (png and jpg), and some of them are zip files.

My goal is to permanently remove every single file except the zip archives. I assume it's some combination of `rm` and `file`, but I'm not sure of the exact syntax.

Comment: are the zip files named 'index.html.n' as well?

Comment: Yes, they all share that name. I believe the `file` command will tell you which type it actually is, I'm just not sure how to use that information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove all files that does not have the following extensions in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642211/remove-all-files-that-does-not-have-the-following-extensions-in-linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it fits into your argument list and no filenames contain colon a simple pipe with `xargs` should do:

```
file * | grep -vi zip | cut -d: -f1 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: Can you explain the above command ?

Answer (score 1):

First `find` to find matching file, then `file` to get file types. `sed` eliminates other file types and also removes everything but the filenames from the output of `file`. lastly, `rm` for deleting:

```
find -name 'index.html.[0-9]*' | \                
    xargs file | \                                
      sed -n 's/\([^:]*\): Zip archive.*/\1/p' |  
        xargs rm
```

Answer (score 1):

I would run:

```
for f in in index.html.*
do
  file "$f" | grep -qi zip
  [ $? -ne 0 ] && rm -i "$f"
done
```

and remove -i option if you feel confident enough

Answer (score 1):

Here's the approach I'd use; it's not entirely automated, but it's less error-prone than some other approaches.

```
file * > cleanup.sh
```

or

```
 file index.html.* > cleanup.sh
```

This generates a list of all files (excluding dot files), or of all `index.html.*` files, in your current directory and writes the list to `cleanup.sh`.

Using your favorite text editor (mine happens to be vim), edit `cleanup.sh`:

- Add `#!/bin/sh` as the first line
- Delete all lines containing the string "`Zip archive`"
- On each line, delete everything from the `:` to the end of the line (in vim, `:%s/:.*$//`)
- Replace the beginning of each line with "`rm`" followed by a space

Exit your editor, updating the file.

```
chmod +x cleanup.sh
```

You should now have a shell script that will delete everything except zip files.

Carefully inspect the script before running it.  Look out for typos, and for files whose names contain shell metacharacters.  You might need to add quotation marks to the file names.

(Note that if you do this as a one-line shell command, you don't have the opportunity to inspect the list of files you're going to delete before you actually delete them.)

Once you're satisfied that your script is correct, run

```
./cleanup.sh
```

from your shell prompt.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in index.html.*
do
    $type = file $i;
    if [[ ! $file =~ "Zip" ]]
    then
        rm $file
    fi
done
```

Change the `rm` to a `ls` for testing purposes.